# "Way out at sea" meaning

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

[enter link description here](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/07/opinion/sunday/brit-marling-women-movies.html)

This is the third question from the editorial "I Don’t Want to Be the Strong Female Lead" from NYtimes.

> Butler felt to me like a lighthouse blinking from an island of understanding way out at sea.

I interpreted this in this way.

"understanding a way out at sea."

The text has no article. But I don't see the other way so I understood this way.

Please interpret this correctly.

Comment: The metaphorical lighthouse on its island is 'way out at sea'

Comment: Your interpretation is incorrect. We typically *don't* include an article in contexts like *He's standing **way** over there.*

Comment: Butler felt to me like a lighthouse blinking from [an island of understanding] way out at sea.

Answer (score 1):

This is an informal usage of "way" as an **adverb**: it means that the lighthouse is *a long way out* at sea.  You could think of it as equivalent to the word "far".  (Personally I think "*way out **to** sea*" reads a bit more nicely).

from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/way :

```
way
adverb
UK  /weɪ/ US  /weɪ/
way adverb (EMPHASIS)

informal
used to emphasize degree or separation, especially in space or time:
*After the third lap, she was way behind the other runners.*
*She spends way too much money on clothes.*
```

For the text as a whole, imagine a comma after "understanding":  understanding is a part of the previous phrase, like so:

*"Butler felt to me like (he was) a lighthouse blinking from an island of understanding, (which was) way out at sea."*

The lighthouse and "island of understanding" are metaphors: they mean that Butler is isolated from others and understands more than others (or perhaps just the writer), and others/the writer just see a glimpse of that understanding when he occasionally communicates it to them.